# connecting string and calculation in pnp

Tags: php

```
<h1>Score and Prize</h1>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="skyblue">SCORE</th>
<th bgcolor="skyblue">PRIZE</th>
</tr>
<?php
$num = 1;
while ($num <= 5){
echo "<tr>
<td>".$num * 50 . "</td>
<td>". $num * 1000 . "</td>
</tr>";
$num++;
}
?>
```

This is a loop to make a table. In the php code, I found out that

```
<td>".$num * 50 . "</td>
```

This is working, but

```
<td>".$num * 50. "</td>
```

This is not working. And only difference is a space between number '50' and '.'.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Please consider properly indenting your code before posting it in Stack Overflow, it helps people who might answer your question to find the problem faster.

Answer (score 6):

php is parsing the 50. as a floating point number, and so it no longer sees the '.' as a string concatenation operator.

Comment: This is one of the reasons that I use `,` instead of `.` for string concatenation when using `echo`, also, `,` doesn't break the interpreter like `.` does.

Comment: @ohgodwhy you can use a commar for concatenation?